# Deep sleep hangs when used with D0 pin when we connect to reset pin in nodemcu

Tags: arduino-uno, nodemcu, sleep

I am using a nodemcu and running a code using hall effect sensor and ultrasonic sensor with deep sleep except the deep sleep keeps hanging when I use this code. With code taken from online it does not hang. What is wrong with my code Please help me!

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <PubSubClient.h>
#define sleepInterval 30 // 6 minutes

// Update these with values suitable for your network.

const char* ssid = "Thief_3h";
const char* password = "lan";
const char* mqtt_server = "ipaddress";
const char* mqtt_topic = "sensors/test/";
const int trigPin = 2;  //D4
const int echoPin = 0;  //D3
long duration;
float distance_cm;
const int hallSensorPin = 14;                      // connect the hall effect sensor on pin 2
const unsigned long sampleTime = 1000;
float radius = 10;
float velocity;
float rdepth = 5;
float cm;
WiFiClient espClient;
PubSubClient client(espClient);
long lastMsg = 0;
char msg[75];
int value = 0;
int rpm;


void setup_wifi() {

  delay(10);
  // We start by connecting to a WiFi network
  Serial.println();
  Serial.print("Connecting to ");
  Serial.println(ssid);

  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);

  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
  }


  Serial.println("");
  Serial.println("WiFi connected");
  Serial.println("IP address: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
}

void callback(char* topic, byte* payload, unsigned int length) {
  Serial.print("Message arrived [");
  Serial.print(topic);
  Serial.print("] ");
  for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    Serial.print((char)payload[i]);
  }
  Serial.println(); 

}

void reconnect() {
  // Loop until we're reconnected
  while (!client.connected()) {
    Serial.print("Attempting MQTT connection...");
    // Create a random client ID
    String clientId = "ESP8266Client-";
    clientId += String(random(0xffff), HEX);
    // Attempt to connect
    if (client.connect(clientId.c_str())) {
      Serial.println("connected");
      // Once connected, publish an announcement...
      client.publish("/test/river/rpm", "starting");
      // ... and resubscribe
      client.subscribe("inTopic");
    } else {
      Serial.print("failed, rc=");
      Serial.print(client.state());
      Serial.println(" try again in 5 seconds");
      // Wait 5 seconds before retrying
      delay(5000);
    }
  }
}




void ultra(){
  delay(2000);
  digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);
  delayMicroseconds(2);
   // Sets the trigPin on HIGH state for 10 micro seconds
  digitalWrite(trigPin, HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds(10);
  digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);
  
  duration = pulseIn(echoPin, HIGH);
  //cm = microsecondsToCentimeters(duration);
  distance_cm = ( duration / 29 ) / 2;rdepth;
}

int getRPM()
{
  int count = 0;
  boolean countFlag = LOW;
  unsigned long currentTime = 0;
  unsigned long startTime = millis();
  while (currentTime <= sampleTime)
  {
    if (digitalRead(hallSensorPin) == HIGH)
    {
      countFlag = HIGH;
    }
    if (digitalRead(hallSensorPin) == LOW && countFlag == HIGH)
    {
      count++;
      countFlag=LOW;
    }
    currentTime = millis() - startTime;
  }
  int countRpm = int(60000/float(sampleTime))*count;
  return countRpm;
}

void goToSleep() {
  ESP.deepSleep(1000000 * sleepInterval);
}

void setup(){
  pinMode(hallSensorPin,INPUT);
  pinMode(trigPin, OUTPUT); // Sets the trigPin as an Output
  pinMode(echoPin, INPUT); // Sets the echoPin as an Input
  //pinMode(D0, WAKEUP_PULLUP);
  delay(1000);
  pinMode(BUILTIN_LED, OUTPUT);     // Initialize the BUILTIN_LED pin as an output
  Serial.begin(9600);
  setup_wifi();
  client.setServer(mqtt_server, 1883);
  client.setCallback(callback);
  if (!client.connected()) {
    reconnect();
  }
  client.loop();
  delay(100);
   rpm = getRPM();
  velocity = (rpm * 2 * 3.14 * radius)/60;
  ultra();
  delay(1000);
  senddata();
  delay(1000);
  goToSleep();

  
}

void senddata(){

distance_cm = ( duration / 29 ) / 2;rdepth;
  
  long now = millis();
  if (now - lastMsg > 2000) {
    lastMsg = now;
    
    snprintf (msg, 75, "Velocity:%6.2f Depth:%.2f", velocity, distance_cm);
    Serial.print("Publish message: ");
    Serial.println(msg);
    
    client.publish(mqtt_topic, msg);
  }
    Serial.print("RPM:");
  Serial.println(rpm);
  Serial.print("Velocity:");
  Serial.println(velocity);
  Serial.print("depth:");
  Serial.println(distance_cm);
 
}

void loop(){}
```

Comment: "With code taken from online it does not hang" With *what* code taken from online?

Comment: Move `client.loop();` into the `loop()`, if your esp going to sleep for 6 minutes, you may also want to `#define MQTT_KEEP_ALIVE 300`. If you are expecting data to be received before go to sleep, then move `ESP.deepSleep(1000000 * sleepInterval);` into the end of the callback function.